# webfont that does not appear on iphone and firefox

Tags: ios, css, firefox, svg, webfonts

Hello (sorry for english i'm french),

The problem is that the font used is not displayed in firefox nor in iOS.

Here is the code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova-Regular';
    src: url('webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
    url('webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.svg#wf') format('svg');
}
```

For the body element :

```
font: normal 1.25em/1.2 ProximaNova-Regular;
```

I tried several things for iOS :

```
AddType image/svg-xml svg
AddType image/svg-xml svgz
```

And for Firefox :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I also checked in the file .svg there is the id wf on the font tag.

THANKS

Comment: try Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox and tell what does it shows?

Comment: If it shows download failed or something try hard refreshing (Ctrl + F5) your browser and if problem persists then we might need to work out.

Comment: I have the same error when i try CTRL+F5

Comment: okies.. not we need to check things now.. give me sometime..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web font doesn’t appear on Chrome or IE either. The reason is simply that the font resources referred to do not exist, i.e. the URLs like http://www.anthonyblochet.fr/css/webfonts/2ACFD6_0_0.woff cause a 404 Not Found response.

Comment: I have forgotten to type ../ in my css to return a file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Try

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
  SetEnvIf Origin »
    "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain1\.org|domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Same problem, i've put your code in .htaccess file in my webfonts folder that's ok ?

I typed CTRL+F5 : same error.